# What does "^" mean in package.json versioning?

Tags: npm

I recently ran `npm install` (npm 1.4.3) with the `--save-dev` flag and the package entries it added to my package.json all began with a `^`, e.g. `"^2.5.0"`. I have never seen this before with the earlier versions of npm I have used, and I cannot find any documentation for this notation, only for the notations I'm already familiar with, e.g. `~`, `>=` etc.. What does it mean?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Quoting from [isaacs/node-semver](https://github.com/isaacs/node-semver):

> - ^1.2.3 := >=1.2.3-0 <2.0.0-0 "Compatible with 1.2.3". When using caret operators, anything from the specified version (including prerelease) will be supported up to, but not including, the next major version (or its prereleases). 1.5.1 will satisfy ^1.2.3, while 1.2.2 and 2.0.0-beta will not.
> - ^0.1.3 := >=0.1.3-0 <0.2.0-0 "Compatible with 0.1.3". 0.x.x versions are special: the first non-zero component indicates potentially breaking changes, meaning the caret operator matches any version with the same first non-zero component starting at the specified version.
> - ^0.0.2 := =0.0.2 "Only the version 0.0.2 is considered compatible"

That said, I would recommend to use "~" instead because it has more intuitive semantics, see discussion in [npm/npm#4587](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4587).

Comment: Thanks. I'll read the discussion you linked but my first impression is that's a really risky new default that just adds another step to my workflow.

Comment: what do you mean by "another step"?

Comment: I mean that I used to rely on the default giving me "~", which I want, so now I have to go manually change it. Not a big deal.

Comment: You don't have to manually change it. Just apply [this patch](https://github.com/rlidwka/yapm/commit/62a97cd293f00d0317f1912aeed9914f682d8378) to your npm installation to make the prefix configurable.

Comment: It's also supported only in certain versions of npm. Any idea which versions those are?

Comment: What if you don't include it? What does it mean?

Answer (score 8):

At a high level (or for quick check):

^2.4.5 = 2.x.x

~2.4.5 = 2.4.x

Answer (score 4):

From [version ranges](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/semver#ranges)

> **Caret Ranges ^1.2.3 ^0.2.5 ^0.0.4**
> Allows changes that do not modify the left-most non-zero digit in the
> [major, minor, patch] tuple. In other words, this allows patch and
> minor updates for versions 1.0.0 and above, patch updates for versions
> 0.X >=0.1.0, and no updates for versions 0.0.X.

> **Tilde Ranges ~1.2.3 ~1.2 ~1**
> Allows patch-level changes if a minor version is specified on the
> comparator. Allows minor-level changes if not.

Answer (score 0):

SIMPLE:

Major.Minor.Patch

Tilde (~) It is used to match the most recent patch version.
It freezes the major & minor version.

﻿﻿﻿~1.2.0 Allowed ====> 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.5……………1.2.x

Caret (^) It is used to match minor & patch updates.

^1.2.4 Allowed ====> 1.3.1, 1.4.2, 1.5.5……………1.X.x.

Comment: This question and its accepted answer are nearly 10 years old. What does this answer add that isn't already covered?